# C shift zero or shift by zero

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am learning program `AVR uCs`.

An example code snippet contains this line:

```
DDRC |= (0 << 0) | (0 << 1); // PIN C0, C1 as input for buttons
```

I don't understand what sense

```
(0 << 0)
```

makes and in general what this line logically does.

I know what the `DDRC` is I only want to understand this logical operation.

**May be the comment helps.**

Comment: Shifting a zero doesn't do much. Did they mean `1 << n`? That would make more sense.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sometimes, when writing to hardware, shifting zero is put in to be explicit about clearing the bit and to make modifying the code to set the bit easier.

Comment: @Skizz by itself, OR-ing a zero does not clear the bit. In fact, this statement only really makes sense if there was a preceding `DDRC = 0;` line before it.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Hmmm, perhaps I'm using the wrong word. Instead of 'clearing', I should have said 'not setting'. When doing low level hardware interface code in the past, I've seen macros set up to allow code like `hardware_reg = (ON << SOMEFLAG) | (OFF << SOMEOTHERFLAG) | (enum_value << ENUMBITPOS)` which would expand to include `0 << bitpos`. This has several benefits, mainly that the intention to initialise a bit to 0 is explicitly declared and hasn't been forgotten by the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The code does nothing and might be wrong.

The author could have meant

```
DDRC |= (1 << 0) | (1 << 1);
```

which is short for

```
DDRC |= 3;
```

which reads the DDRC, sets the bottommost two bits, and writes that value back. The syntax using `<<` and `|` attempts to make that clearer.

An alternative interpretation would be that the author intends to clear these two bits. In that case, the code is wrong, because it doesn't do that.

If the `DDRC` is the Data Direction Register for port C, chances are that writing a zero bit switches the direction to input, in which case the intention appears to be clearing the bits.

The appropriate code for that would be

```
DDRC &= ~( (1 << 0) | (1 << 1) );
```

Comment: The code could be perfectly correct, if you want to set those two bits to zero. The RHS to the shifts would normally be named constants, a bit like `(1 << FLAG1) | (0 << FLAG2)`, so you're explicitly setting FLAG1 to 1 and FLAG2 to zero. Also makes toggling the bit easier.

Comment: No, because the bits are ORed together with the previous value.

Comment: True, but we haven't got the preceding code, it could be `int DDRC=0;` or the result of setting up other bits.

Comment: Indeed, but I have the strong suspicion that this is a hardware register.

Comment: @Skizz Your first comment is rather misleading, the line does nothing to clear any bits, unless there's more code which isn't seen? That's not making a lot of sense. It doesn't set the bits, which of course is not the same thing as clearing them.

Comment: So if i understand you right, this line is needless. It does not set or clear anything

Comment: In the present form, it does nothing (but if `DDRC` is declared `volatile`, the read and write accesses are still emitted, which may have an effect on hardware).

Comment: I've included your ideas into the answer, as it may indeed be the author's intention to clear the bits.